# How to modify DNA without using computers?

Tags: science-based, biology, genetic-engineering

I would like for a civilization to be very good at bio-engineering, but I do not know how they would be able to modify DNA to suit their purposes, with greater things than breeding can bring. For example, giving natural armor to certain animals so they could take bullets.

Or more important to this species, they are interested in giving an animal, which spits acid, armor and turning it into a gun of sorts. The animal has not developed armor, and has no DNA coding for armor to really work off of. Any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Computers don't actually play a critical role in gene sequencing aside from being a wonderful place to store data and crunch numbers. The actual work is done chemically.

Comment: You can do everything a computer does by hand, it just takes longer.

Comment: Do you need the DNA specifically changed or do you just need this creature to have these abilities?

Comment: @Unhappymarshmellow The creature needs to obtain armor, and it would be best if it could pass on the abilites, so I would think the DNA would be specifically changed.

Comment: Bioengineer a biocomputer....

Comment: What's acid armor? How do you spit armor?

Comment: @sphennings Were into another question territory here, but how would one do that?

Comment: @OneSurvivor Well I was thinking maybe cross-breading, but that really depends on the world this takes place in. You mentioned guns, so it must take place relatively recently, now or in the future.

Comment: @sphennings Acid armor is an error. Commas save lives.

Comment: @Unhappymarshmellow It would function similarly to a gun, accelerating a projectile from you to your target, but it has nothing to do with our guns. It chucks some form of acid at you.

Comment: Don't know.  If they're "very good bio-engineers" and are engineering shapeshifting bio-guns, it stands to reason that they'd use a bio-computer.

Comment: @sphennings Okay, did a bit of research. I have a fuzzy idea what they would look like, but it makes the question moot.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, if nobody did that already! While every Stack Exchange site has its own distinct differences, Worldbuilding is “more different” in some ways. In particular, you ought not Accept an answer before waiting at least 24 hours. A full explaination can be found on [this meta post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5023).

Comment: @anon I couldn't disagree more. Yes, you can do the basic chemistry synthesis steps by hand and in theory do the same thing as high throughput methods, but in practice, it's totally different. Shotgun sequencing is how we sequenced the human genome, and simply wouldn't have been possible without intensive computation. There's a scale factor here where computation moves from "time saver" to "indispensable". Modern bio-engineering cannot be done without computers.

Comment: @NuclearWang so you are saying it is biologically impossible to replace the computer with an organically computational structure. That it is impossible for an alien species to have the mental capacity to perform all the same computation.

Comment: @anon I never said the computer couldn't be organic, it just has to be able to compute. If this alien race possess brains that can do computation and pattern matching at the rate of gigaflops, good for them, but that's really just changing the definition of what we call a "computer". Biological systems we're familiar with don't even come close. What I'm saying is that doing modern bioengineering without having that computational power at your disposal, in one form or another, is not possible.

Comment: @NuclearWang I never said computational power wasn't critical, what I said was "computers" weren't necessary. If you can swap a computer for an organic computer "brain" Than you have achieved the result. This is moot as the OP changed their question effectively.

Comment: @OneSurvivor , unfortunalty what you want is closer to the trope of LEGO Genetics (http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LegoGenetics) and is not really possible with real world earth genetics. Potentally on the upside if this is a fantacy on Space Opera setting you are not committed to Earth genetics.

Comment: @PChapman I suppose I see where you are coming from, but I don't see this as a "wow, we can slap whatever we want on instantly". It would take a lot of time and experimentation, but it would be eventually possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Short answer: You Can't**

The [Human Genome Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Genome_Project) began "on a napkin" in 1984 and was declared complete in 2003.  That's 19 years with access to overwhelming computational power.  So, no, you can't manipulate DNA without computers.

> **Long answer: What's a computer?**

Some years ago I coined a phrase, "technology dichotomy."  The phrase describes the occasional author who wants, for example, time travel without first inventing the wheel.  In your case it's the development of advanced bio-engineering without computers.  The reality of technology is that you can't progress from one point to another without a vast pyramid of knowledge extending out below it.

[DNA was discovered](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/science/add_edexcel/cells/dnarev3.shtml) using x-rays.  Radioactivity (from whence x-rays come) comes from the study of material physics.  As does, among many other things, electronics.  To justify no electricity-driven computers on your world you would basically need to justify no electricity ... except that electricity is a fundamental component of life and there's always some kite-and-key-weilding goombah trying to figure out how something works for no better reason than it's there.  But that ignores the idea of "computers" generally.

Let's look at reality: as you understand more things, the foundation math gets more complex with it.  As the complexity of math increases, the need to crunch it faster than a pencil and paper will allow increases.  End result: a computer.  But wait....

Most people don't realize the etymology of the word "computer" comes from the 1600s (yup, the *sixteen-hundreds*), meaning "one [a person] who calculates."  In the beginning all computers were people.  Then came mechanical computers like the [Babbage Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine), then came electrically-driven mechanical computers, then (FINALLY!) came electronics.

**It's *impossible* for an intelligent species to develop *accounting* without the need to expand to something faster than pencil and paper.**  Why do I say accounting?  I can't prove it, but I'll eat my hat if the reason for the first computer (person) wasn't *money.*  Some greasy politician wanted to total up his <s>bribes,</s> I mean <s>take,</s> I mean *benefits.*  And computers were born.  (Seriously, it was undoubtadly the Rothschildes... you know it was the Rothschilds....  If you think someone's out to get you, you're probably right....)

**Therefore, the answer is "no, you can't do it without a computer, but what's stopping your species from developing computers?"**

Bear in mind that it's unlikely that a society that is biologically based wouldn't understand electron transfer and solid-state physics.  They may find a way to do it without silicon, but they'd still have computers.

Comment: Okay, will keep the final question in mind.

Answer (score 4):

I would beg to make a difference between

- changing a DNA of a test object
- changing a DNA of a test object in a meaningful manner.

Just to insert stuff into a DNA is... well, it's hard, but it's Sci-Fi easy. Viruses do it all the time. However, you need to limit the self-replication, you need to attack each and every cell in an organism, you need to work around the immune system.

It might be easier to attack the progenitor cells of the male gamete and to wait what happens with the offspring.

---

That is the influence of the first kind is short of random, not goal-oriented at all. But totally doable without computers. In the long run it might produce interesting results. Just remember that we (as in, the humanity) managed to turn wolves into both chihuahua and mastiffs without any DNA editing at all. It took a long time, however.

Answer (score 2):

Grafting, not DNA modification.
We can stick parts of plants together and they grow together and live as one.  On your planet, they can do that with animals, either through some innate compatibility or via a substance they discovered.

Characteristics like thicker plates can be selectively bread using conventional techniques, and then these separate parts assembled into the desired livestock.

Answer (score 1):

Your people want to take a creature that spits acid, give it armor, and make it into a gun.  You do not need to engineer DNA to do that.

You can give it armor.
[image: elephant armor]
http://theminiaturespage.com/news/talk/msg.mv?id=708758

You can train it to spit on command.

[image: spitting beluga]
http://themiddleflipper.blogspot.com/2016/02/whats-in-name-of-behavior-that-is.html

Whether or not you can tote it around like a musket depends on the size of the creature.

Answer (score 0):

Erg my point didn't seem to inspire anyone, anyways

Intentional and direct Genetic Engineering requires vast amounts of knowledge and computational resources. So the one way I see to achieve this without computers is for your species to have such evolved brains that they can intentionally GE using their minds as a substitute for computers.

Selective breeding and grafting are great and all but they are more akin to genetic manipulation than true genetic engineering.

Without the ability to fully understand the genome and biology and be able to craft target mutators its likely they wont achieve the dramatic effects you are looking for (provided something similar doesn't already exist in your world).

**Note:** the actual process of editing genes is achieved without computers through chemicals, retro viruses, and the imprecise gun method. You need to the computational power to craft and guide these tools.

At this rate your species could then even GE creatures as function of their own biology (though farfetched) makes for fun possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer to [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/96357/what-would-a-spacecraft-built-by-a-cephalopod-race-look-like) as my conclusion was similar (entirely different question though).

Octopuses are amazing creatures who have the ability to edit their genetic code by choosing to alter and/or ignore instructions for their DNA. There may be a correlation between octopuses' relatively high intelligence and their ability to do this innate genetic tinkering.

If your civilization rose from roots similar to those of octopuses, genetic tinkering would be in their blood, perhaps literally. As their civilization advanced, their advancement would through improved their ability to genetically modify their surroundings, much as we have improved our methods of farming, building, fighting, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that DNA hybridization was first developed in the early 1970s. It was not done using computers, just a lot of lab work to refine enzymes, culture cells, hybridize using viruses and other vectors and so on. Computers were not that common in labs until the PCs in the 1980s. You can certainly do biotechnology without computers, it is just hard work.

Comment: That's not accurate... Hybridization itself may not have required a computer, but all the technologies, reagents and information they needed to be able to perform hybridization would not be possible to achieve without computational tools

Comment: @Thai: Any example? You can do x-ray crystallography to find structures without computers. Sure there was calculation around, but slide rules used to dominate. Computers back then were remote mainframes for particular jobs, not lab work.

Answer (score 0):

Simple reproduction would change the DNA of the resultant being. Maternal DNA and Paternal DNA would combine randomly and generate a new DNA sequence in the child. After generations go by more new sequences are formed. Genetics is a crap shoot. It does not require a computer and is far more fun.